# Using thread goes wrong and calls abort() method and stops my application

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

After i added the for loop which creates multiple threads in the main method the application broke. Any idea what the issue here is?

It's an simple application that opens a socket. I want to do this multple times to test my server.

```
    #include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <string>
#include <thread> 
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;
void myFunc() {
    while (true) {

        string ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";         // IP Address of the server
        int port = 11111;                       // Listening port # on the server

        WSADATA WsaDat;
        if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &WsaDat) != 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Winsock error - Winsock initialization failed\r\n";
            WSACleanup();
            system("PAUSE");
            return;
        }

        // Create our socket
        SOCKET Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        if (Socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            std::cout << "Winsock error - Socket creation Failed!\r\n";
            WSACleanup();
            system("PAUSE");
            return;
        }

        sockaddr_in hint;
        hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
        hint.sin_port = htons(port);
        inet_pton(AF_INET, ipAddress.c_str(), &hint.sin_addr);

        // Connect to server
        int connResult = connect(Socket, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));
        if (connResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            cerr << "Can't connect to server, Err #" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
            closesocket(Socket);
            WSACleanup();
            return;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    std:cout << "Application started!\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        thread _newThread(myFunc);
    }
}
```

Cpp isn't my programming language. I wrote a similair application in c# and it worked fine. Any idea what i'm doing wrong here?

What am i trying to accomplish?

- Opening Socket connection multiple times
- Using threads to speed up the process
- No need to send/receive data
- Sockets should stay connected

Comment: I'm still quite new to the Standard Library and the `thread` class - but it looks to me like you are trying to re-create the same `thread` object 25 times.

Comment: @Adrian "_but it looks to me like you are trying to re-create the same thread object 25 times._" What do you mean by "re-create"? It tries to create 25 threads, each going out of scope, at each iteration, of the loop.

Comment: @Adrian Well Isn't it creating new instance at every loop?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Like I said, I'm new to this sort of stuff!